# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer just not working in tomcat, please help

Tags: spring, tomcat, placeholder

In my webapp which is deployed in tomcat environment, I have one spring configuration file which contains placeHolder, like ${myurl}. To replace the placeholder, I created applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF directory which contains a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurater bean and set its location to a properties file which also inside WEB-INF directory.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
<bean id="placeHolderConfigurer"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="WEB-INF/my.properties"/>
 </bean>
  <import resource="classpath*:META-INF/springFile1.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Then in web.xml, I specify the context:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

In WEB-INF/my.properties
myurl=http://www.google.com

This is the springFile1.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="placeholderConfig"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${" />
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}" />
</bean>
<bean id="mycache" class="com.abc.MyURL"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">

    <constructor-arg value="${myurl}" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

I keep getting the unparsed value ${myurl}

I tried to put properties file in classpath, absolute path, and WEB-INF, all result the same.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of listing the xml files in web.xml, try importing them in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<import resource="classpath*:springFile1.xml"/>
```

Update: It appears you are redefining the placeholder configurer in the child xml, thus overriding the one from the parent, which specifies the target properties file. Remove the configurer declaration from the child xml.

Comment: @BlueDolphin please show the properties file, and the xml file.

Comment: properties file just one line: myurl=http://www.myurl.com. the application context xml file is showing above, except added line of <import resource="classpath*:META-INF/springFile1.xml"/> I tried to put that line above and after the bean definition. got the same result. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, for the same spring files, if I load from standalone application, and use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
       Properties properties = new Properties(); properties.put("myurl", "http://www.myurl.com"); context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);  then it works fine.

Comment: @BlueDolphin - I meant - show the springFile1.xml. You can edit your question and add that information